# How can I convert this select statement into an insert table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I've found answers online, but none with specifically what I am doing. I couldn't get anything to work.

I have a select that randomly selects records and I just want to be able to have it insert into a table instead.

My SQL is

```
with data as (
select *, row_number() over (partition by DIVISION order by DIVISION) as rn
    from WORK
)
select *
from data
where rn <= @randomNumber or (rn - @randomNumber) % 18 = 1 AND DIVISION != 4;
```

I know I am not supposed to do the partition by DIVISION order by DIVISION but that's a separate issue I believe.

I just need to be able to insert this data into another table WORK_CLEAN

Comment: You should probably put the extra `DIVISION` filter inside the CTE. But as it stands you'll have problems because the two `OR` conditions need to be in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an insert statement.

```
with data as (
select *, row_number() over (partition by DIVISION order by DIVISION) as rn
    from WORK
)
insert yourTable ([ColumnsHere])
select *
from data
where rn <= @randomNumber or (rn - @randomNumber) % 18 = 1 AND DIVISION != 4;
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this be all columns? Can I use * in this case? The table structures are 100% identical.

Comment: You could use * but always suggest that you explicitly name your columns. You could skip the list of columns but if anything changes in either table your code is broken.

Comment: Whenever I try to use this, it tells me that whatever table I choose is an invalid object.

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying because this syntax will work.